# SQLilte Searching with prefix String by using Match

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-sqlite

I am using FTS3, to get content from DB and i need to get Strings with prefix (Content only start with that string). But when i use MATCH it acts like Contains.

Here example :

NOW: 
Input: 123
OUTPUT: 123abc
        123aaa
        aaa123

What I Want: 
Input: 123
OUTPUT: 123abc
        123aaa

Here My code :

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLConstants.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + SQLConstants.TABLE_NAME + " MATCH '" + input + "*' ORDER BY " + CODE
        + " ASC;", null);
```

Comment: Works for me. Does your data really contain "123aaa"? Aren't there any other characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For goals like yours is usually used `LIKE` clause.

> The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified
>   pattern in a column.

```
String value = "something";
```

Explanation:

```
like value + "%"; --> return everything that starts with value and behind it can be anything
like % + value; --> return everything that ends with value and before it can be anything
% + like value + "%"; --> return everything that contains value and before and behind it can be anything
```

In your case you need first case so:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + SQLConstants.TABLE_NAME 
         + " WHERE " + SQLConstants.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?
             ORDER BY " + CODE + " ASC", new String[] {input + "%"});
```

Now it will works.

Comment: what is CODE supposed to be in this string?

Answer (score 0):

use LIKE with % instead of Match with *